# C# extracting a single variable from html document from a website

Tags: c#, html, xpath

This is what it looks like.
[image: html]

I've tried something like this:

```
var url = "https://www.tek-zence.no/";
var httpsClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpsClient.GetStringAsync(url);

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

var element = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(node => !node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("feature-nummer")).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(element.Innertext);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello. You can try [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net) for extracting elemets from html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One problem is you are negating your condition with `!`. You don't actually say what you are trying to do, but based on your screenshot you want to find the div that contains that class, not divs that do not contain that class. And then you `ToString()` the resultant sequence and try to get `InnerText`. String does not have an InnerText property. And when I say "sequence" I mean that query will return a collection, not a single element so you can't tread it as such.

Answer (score 0):

With HtmlAgilityPack, you can do this:

```
var text = @"<div><div class='feature-nummer'>01</div></div>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);

int number = -1;
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'feature-nummer')]");
if (div != null && int.TryParse(div.InnerText, out int value))
{
    number = value;
}
```

The HTML here is just a sample like your HTML. Must work with your HTML too.

Comment: Now, this works well, and thanks for taking your time to help, but what if I needed to get out a string element, which could work with both numbers and letters?
signed: Young grasshopper

Comment: Yes, div.InnerText has the string. In this case, knowing that is a number, I try to parse to number but you can use the string. Also, InnerHtml gives you the HTML.